# How to test or clean implicit output buffer in PHP on server

Tags: php, buffer

I want to show two different error messages.

1. The nice, HTML page describing error before outputting.
2. The simple string after partially outputted content.

I can use `headers_sent` to test if something was outputted. Unfortunately there is implicit output buffer and there can be some content. I can flush it, but this will send headers too.

Can I clean this **implicit output buffer** or check if it is empty?

P.S.
I don't want to use explicit buffers. The desired content may be an image, CSV file, HTML file, plain text file, different BLOB, nothing (only headers) or something else.

Comment: Why should I use the asynchronous JavaScript and XML?

Comment: I assumed you wanted html outputted and then more content appended somewhere after the initial page/error has loaded...

Comment: I'm looking for a generic solution for any kind of content. There may be problems with generating XML too.